# Why this simple jQuery 'addClass' is not working in this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lazy-loading

I've tested the jQuery addClass : [fiddle](http://goo.gl/A7rmZ6)
That works fine.

The jQuery adds a class called `lazy` to the image.

Now I want to do the same in a wordpress site.
So I've added following code in my `functions.php`

```
function smart_magazine_scripts_styles() { 
        wp_enqueue_script('lazyloadscriot', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.lazyload-any.min.js', array(), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-by', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-by.js', array(), '1.0', true);
    }
```

When I see the site source code I see both `lazyload-any.min.js` and `custom-by.js` are loaded fine.

custom-by.js has following line only :

```
jQuery('img').addClass('lazy');
```

But when I check the images there is no class called `lazy` is added to them.

Why is that?
Here is the [site](http://goo.gl/5wpDUK)

Comment: Is jQuery itself loaded?

Comment: yes. site already has jQuery for it's slider.. so I think no need to add jQuery again..

Comment: Firebug said.. "jQuery not defined" try instead of jQuery -> $

Comment: open up browser console and check... jQuery is not working at all.

Comment: that's what. but as you see the jquery is in here : `js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1`

Comment: In your case jquery is not present at the time of binding/selecting elements.It is loading lateron

Comment: Now it's fixed.. jQuery is loaded. Please check again..

Comment: In your case jquery is not present at the time of binding/selecting elements.It is loading lateron

Comment: Try using it is on DOM ready

Comment: Sometimes I wonder whether or not this question is spam or for real.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your document is ready? Try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('img').addClass('lazy');
});
```

Comment: still same.. but people are starting to downVOTE even they do not say a solution or why..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this instead

```
$(function()
{
    $('img').addClass('lazy');
});
```

If you are trying to target an element with the class img you need to use .img or if you are trying to target an element with the id img you need to use #img

To load jQuery from Google just put this line in your HTML file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When your function is executed jQuery may no have not been loaded yet. 
First, try to put your JavaScript inside a $(function() like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('img').addClass('lazy');
});
```

Of course if you wait for the DOM to be ready and then add the class lazy to your images there is no point. The best would be to add the class in the static templates or with PHP.

Comment: yup.. I tried this too: `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('img').addClass('lazy'); });` but still same

Comment: can you please try this: jQuery(document).ready(function() { console.log('jquery is ready for use') }); Do you see something inside your console?

Comment: I've got it.. those images have NO class added are from an external site

Comment: Can you explain? Even if an image is an external image it should still receive the correct class. Maybe lazyload doesn't work with external resources?

Comment: ooh.. but it's not about `lazyload` now.. I thought it doesn't work because images and it's whole HTML block from an external site